# MSDTC fails for self-hosted NServiceBus ASP.NET endpoints but not other processes

Tags: asp.net, .net, transactions, nservicebus, msdtc

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that hosts many back end NServiceBus endpoints.  All of the services that rely on the NServiceBus.Host.exe host (installed as Windows Services) are able to interact with MSDTC perfectly, averaging a small handful of concurrent distributed transactions throughout the day.  There are 2 small Web.API applications, however, that self host NServiceBus endpoints (as publishers) that constantly receive the following error when trying to process subscription requests:

> NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy Error in receiving
>   messages. System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The
>   transaction has aborted. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException:
>   Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The Transaction Manager
>   is not available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D01B)    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ConnectToProxy(String
>   nodeName, Guid resourceManagerIdentifier, IntPtr managedIdentifier,
>   Boolean& nodeNameMatches, UInt32& whereaboutsSize, CoTaskMemHandle&
>   whereaboutsBuffer, IResourceManagerShim& resourceManagerShim)    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException
>   comException)    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.get_ProxyShimFactory()
>   at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.CreateTransaction(TransactionOptions
>   properties)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromoted.EnterState(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout,
>   Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped,
>   ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32
>   action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter,
>   MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction,
>   MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)    at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive(TimeSpan timeout,
>   MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)    at
>   NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.ReceiveMessage(Func`1
>   receive) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line
>   313

Some other notes:

- Both the erroring ApplicationPools' identities and the Windows
  Services' Log On users are the same.
- This actually worked well before
  a recent reboot, as the Web.API services were able to successfully
  process subscription requests, and are able to publish messages just
  fine (though publishing does not automatically use MSDTC, and we are
  not using a TransactionScope explicitly).  Since the local reboot, we
  simply get the above error if a subscription request message sits
  in either of the Web.API publisher's input queue.
- I've used both procmon.exe and MSDTC tracing and have found nothing of interest. The typical event viewer logs also do not provide any information.
- All endpoints are running .NET 4.5 and NServiceBus 4.6
- We cannot
  recreate this in any other environment.

**Additional notes from below conversations**

- The thread which throws the exception is pure NServiceBus subscription management where none of "my" code is involved.  When the application pool starts the w3wp.exe worker process on demand, NSB is spawning a worker thread unbeknownst to the application to process subscription requests.  It *should* only ever work across the publisher's input queue and the subscription storage, which I'm using MSMQ for that as well, in a queue right beside the other (i.e. no other server is involved to my knowledge).
- The "code" of the website didn't change across reboots, and the application pool stopped and restarted several times before the reboot without issue.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? I've had the same problem because (supposedly) magically our DTC no long had network access. I know this question is over 3 months old but I'm curious to see what the resolution was. My problem was fixed via: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc753510(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "fixed" this for us in the production environment was adding the application pool identity user to the local Administrators group on the server.  Unfortunately we don't have time to determine what setting required that security setup, as this isn't a required configuration in other similar servers.  Also, this isn't the most desirable solution from a security perspective, but in our particular situation, we're willing to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

What part of your operation requires DTC?  A Distributed Transaction gets enlisted automatically when needed, usually when you are talking to two different DTC-supporting bits of infrastructure (e.g. MSMQ and a database).

You said you tested via DTC tracing--do you mean [DTC Ping](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868)?  Did you test by having it run on both machines (or all machines if there are more than two involved in the transaction)?  The DTC tool is pretty esoteric, and its output can be confusing.

Also, if it did work before the reboot, is it possible the reboot reset firewall settings?  Firewalls are a common cause of DTC problems.

Also, I assume you checked and rechecked your DTC settings on the local machine?  Did you ensure that your MSMQ queues are set up to be transactional?

**From your comments:**

> Note that this particular failure occurs when attempting to dequeue a
>   message from a local private MSMQ queue [...]

The stack trace makes it appear that that's all it's doing, but I suspect that as it is attempting dequeue it is also trying to enlist the transaction between multiple servers.  See below.

> Why MSDTC? It's the original way to support exactly-once messaging in
>   NServiceBus (see here).

Right, but what I'm asking is why the particular operation *requires* a distributed transaction.  If all a handler is doing is reading from a queue and (for example) writing output to the console, MSDTC will never be enlisted, even though the handler is wrapped in a transaction scope.  It will simply use a local transaction to read from the queue.  The escalation to a distributed transaction is automatic, and only happens when it is needed to support multiple bits of infrastructure.

So if you recently deployed code in a handler that writes data to a new database server, you may be getting a failure because you are now enlisting a transaction that includes the new server, which may be where the failure is happening.

So determining all the servers involved in the distributed transaction is the first step.  The next step would be to check the DTC settings on all involved servers.  If DTC settings aren't the problem, I'd recommend testing communication between the servers using DTCPing.  The [NServiceBus documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/transactions-message-processing#distributed-transaction-coordinator) has some good instructions for using DTCPing.

Comment: _Why MSDTC?_ It's the original way to support exactly-once messaging in NServiceBus (see [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/running-on-windows)).  Here's what I mean by [DTC Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678917(v=vs.85).aspx).  _MSDTC settings_: double and triple checked.

Comment: _DTCPing_: I haven't used this on this server as MSDTC is working fine for all other processes.  Note that this particular failure occurs when attempting to dequeue a message from a _local_ private MSMQ queue, which all other services are executing seamlessly within distributed transactions.  Again, all those other services are running as the same user, just not within the context of IIS.

Comment: _Did firewall settings changed on reboot?_ This is an interesting question, as it could be a possibility.  I'll dig into this a little more, but is there some low level tracing/logging/debugging I can use to determine if this is a problem, outside of what's already been mentioned?  I figured procmon.exe would catch tcp/ip connection issues, but I did not see any of those.

Comment: Update: the Windows firewall is turned off for this server.

Comment: Added to my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Ah, gotcha on the "why DTC?".  See my additional notes above in response.  It's possible I've mistaken which queue interaction caused the error (input vs subscription storage), and I'll look into that, though I'll mainly be looking at NServiceBus code, and not any of my own.  Also, are you sure a TransactionScope doesn't simply reach out to MSDTC during the first enlistment?  You could draw that conclusion based on the stack, but I will say I'm not an expert on those internal details of TransactionScope.

Comment: It does appear that way from the stack, but it's hard to say without being familiar with the source code.  Transaction scope _should_ automatically promote to a DT when needed, but it can be forced into a DT if it is coded that way.  I doubt the NSB devs coded it that way, but can't be 100% sure without looking at the source code. For reference:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms131083(v=sql.120).aspx.

Comment: It's possible that it needs to _contact_ the DTC to ensure that it _can_ enlist a DT if needed, without actually enlisting the DT.  I think that was what you were asking?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by it "simply reaching out to MSDTC".  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82752/discussion-between-phil-sandler-and-rossbeehler).